# Rails Tutorial Lesson 8 current user not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey all stuck in lesson 8 of rails tutorial Michael Hartl my logged_in? function doesn't seem to be working since my navbar is not showing the list items for being logged in and instead showing the opposite nor is the link to Profile working

Here is my code.Any help would be greatly appreciated

application.html.erb

```
<header class = "navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class = "container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", home_path, id: "logo" %>
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

 <% if logged_in? %>
                <li> <%= link_to "Home", home_path %> </li>
                <li> <%= link_to "About", about_path %> </li>
                <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Account <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                      <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li>
                        <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
            <% else %>
                <li> <%= link_to "Home", home_path %> </li>
                <li> <%= link_to "About", about_path %> </li>
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
            <% end %>
```

sessionshelper.rb

```
  module SessionsHelper
    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end

    # returns true if the user is logged in

    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

  end
```

Comment: Is `current_user` returning an User instance?

Comment: Want to know where are you calling method "log_in(user)"?

Comment: I think i called it in the sessions controller

Comment: Oh wait i didn't it works now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the code in def current_user with the long form -

```
if @current_user.nil?
  @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
else
  @current_user
end
```

and test if it works

```
def current_user

    if @current_user.nil?
      @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    else
      @current_user
    end

end
```